# SQL Design and Query a Table for storing Combinations

Tags: sql, combinations, permutation

I was looking to store combinations of two fields (not permutations - order does not matter). For example, lets say I have two integer fields: A and B. I want to store the combination (1, 2). Meaning if I looked up "1", and I should see [2], and if I lookup "2", I should see [1].

My first guess was to create a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE RelatedIntegers (
    A INT,        
    B INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(A, B)
);
INSERT INTO RelatedIntegers VALUES (1, 2)
```

However, its entirely possible to store (2, 1) which would be a duplicate combination, but not permutation. Further, if I only store (1, 2), that means I have to perform a more complex query on both A and B to ensure I get all the necessary information.

The only approach I see is that I need to store each permutation, so that I can perform a quick lookup on A, and have B include whatever values I need. However, this also means I must store redundant information to ensure data integrity. If I need to store redundant information, what would be a recommended way to ensure all combinations are stored (and easily deleted)? I was thinking ensuring that the application that uses the database generates the necessary permutations on insert. The other idea I had was to use data base triggers on each insert/delete, but I imagine that might be more confusing.

Comment: Are you asking how to find and remove existing duplicate permutations or prevent a duplicate from being added

Comment: How to prevent duplicates from being added, and how to query the table efficiently. If its not possible, then what is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a check constraint to force an order of the values in the pairs.

```
CREATE TABLE relatedintegers
             (a integer,
              b integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (a,
                           b),
             CHECK (a < b));
```

That way `(1, 2)` can be inserted, but `(2, 1)` cannot. (Change `<` to `<=`, if pairs like `(1, 1)` are also OK. Or switch to `>` (or `>=`), if that makes more sense in your case.)

And in a query to get all the records where the pair contains a value `<n>` at any position, you can use `IN`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM relatedintegers
       WHERE <n> IN (a,
                     b);
```

Comment: I believe this solves my question. I don't think this trick works for storing non integer-based information (such as GUIDs) but it does work. However, while it works, it may be confusing as the application must ensure that (a < b), otherwise an error will be thrown. 

When checking `WHERE <n> in (a, b)`, would there be a performance hit compared to storing each permutation, and checking just column `a`?

Comment: @GLJ: "would there be a performance hit compared to storing each permutation, and checking just column `a`" -- Maybe... That depends, among others, on the DBMS you're actually using, amount of data and the exact query.